# Capybara and Javascript onbefoureunload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, webdriver

I have an 'ask_a_question' page with an onbeforeunload function to alert the user before leaving something unsaved (hey! like SO :P). I'm testing it using cucumber with capybara and webdriver, adding the @javascript tag because it uses a lot of javascript. A cucumber feature might look like this:

```
@javascript
Scenario: add a question
    Given I login as "Mauricio"
    And I go to the create question page 
    Then I should see "Ask a Question" within "header"
```

But once the test pases, Capybara (or WebDriver, I dunno) tries to reuse the same browser window for other tests then the onbeforeunload alert is displayed screwing the following test.

As my feature is not closing or exiting the page per se. I don't think it might be good idea  to add something to accept the alert. But honestly I'm quite lost.

How can I tell capybara to use a new browser window for each @javascript test or automatically close the onbeforeunload alert?

Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss ([docs here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#Javascript_Alert/Confirm)) to get rid of the alert.

You could put this in a cucumber after hook

```
After "@javascript" do
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
  # or accept it if that is what you prefer
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
end
```

Comment: works as a charm with page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept please update the answer.

Comment: yep, it closes the alert but without leaving the current page. with accept the "do you really want to leave the page?" is accepted and the page is left.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, I get non-descript fails in the cukes, and the accept button isn't clicked. Is there something else I need to do to set this up?

Comment: what version of selenium are you using?

Comment: Thanks Derek, your post helped me realise that this dialog can be accessed in the same way as an alert.

Answer (score 2):

A similar answer for anyone using Rspec and Capybara.  This code visits 'about:blank' after each test.

```
context 'page that displays an alert when navigating away' do

  after(:each) do
    begin
      accept_confirm { visit('about:blank') }
    rescue Capybara::ModalNotFound
      # For examples that don't end with an alert
    end
  end

  ...
end
```